# align textview at bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

**Here's my layout code;**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/main_bg" >

<!-- Logo -->

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rel_jobDesc1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="47dip"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/logo" >
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="340dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dip" >

    <!-- JOB DESCRIPTION -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_JOB_DESCRIPTION"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:text="Job Description:"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="14dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_JOB_DESCRIPTION11"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt_JOB_DESCRIPTION"
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true" >
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_JDESCRIPTION"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edit_JOB_DESCRIPTION11"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dip"
        android:text="(Job title, industry, keywords)"
        android:textColor="#4a596e"
        android:textSize="12dip" >
    </TextView>
    <!--  -->


    <!-- LOCATION -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_JOB_LOCATION"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_JDESCRIPTION"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dip"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_SEARCH"
        android:text="Location:          "
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_JOB_LOCATION1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edit_JOB_DESCRIPTION11"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_JDESCRIPTION"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true" >
    </EditText>

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/txt_JLOCATION"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edit_JOB_LOCATION1"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dip"
        android:text="(City, State, Zip)"
        android:textColor="#4a596e"
        android:textSize="12dip" >
    </TextView>
    <!--  -->


    <!-- JOB ID -->
    <!--  -->


    <!-- SEARCH BUTTON -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_search1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_JLOCATION"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dip"
        android:background="@drawable/draw"
        android:text="  Search  " >
    </Button>
    <!--  -->

      <TextView
            style="flat_detail_name"
            android:capitalize="characters"
          android:id="@+id/textView2"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_below="@+id/btn_search1"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
          android:text="Sign in Or Register for Your Primium free membership "
          />

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_Login1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/draw"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="  Login  " />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_register"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/draw"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Register" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_lostlogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/draw"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Lost Login" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rel_jobDesc1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
    android:text="Get Started with Your Job Search"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="14dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

i want to set **Sign IN or Register for your Premium membership**   textview at top of the Login Register And Lost Login Button

Plz help me how we can set this text view

sorry for bad English Any help is appreciated. 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `android:layout_above="@id/btn_Login1"` in `TextView`

I have Just Edited Your Xml File. Use This:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/main_bg" >

<!-- Logo -->

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rel_jobDesc1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="47dip"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/logo" >
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="340dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dip" >

    <!-- JOB DESCRIPTION -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_JOB_DESCRIPTION"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:text="Job Description:"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="14dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_JOB_DESCRIPTION11"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt_JOB_DESCRIPTION"
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true" >
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_JDESCRIPTION"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edit_JOB_DESCRIPTION11"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dip"
        android:text="(Job title, industry, keywords)"
        android:textColor="#4a596e"
        android:textSize="12dip" >
    </TextView>
    <!--  -->


    <!-- LOCATION -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_JOB_LOCATION"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_JDESCRIPTION"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dip"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_SEARCH"
        android:text="Location:          "
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_JOB_LOCATION1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edit_JOB_DESCRIPTION11"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_JDESCRIPTION"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true" >
    </EditText>

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/txt_JLOCATION"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edit_JOB_LOCATION1"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dip"
        android:text="(City, State, Zip)"
        android:textColor="#4a596e"
        android:textSize="12dip" >
    </TextView>
    <!--  -->


    <!-- JOB ID -->
    <!--  -->


    <!-- SEARCH BUTTON -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_search1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_JLOCATION"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dip"
        android:background="@drawable/draw"
        android:text="  Search  " >
    </Button>
    <!--  -->



</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:id="@+id/btnParent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_Login1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/draw"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="  Login  " />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_register"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/draw"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Register" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_lostlogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/draw"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Lost Login" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
            style="flat_detail_name"
            android:capitalize="characters"
          android:id="@+id/textView2"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_above="@id/btnParent"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
          android:text="Sign in Or Register for Your Primium free membership "
          />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rel_jobDesc1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
    android:text="Get Started with Your Job Search"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="14dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: when i am using error: android:layout_above="@id/btn_Login1"              Then getting Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_above' with value '@id/btn_Login1').

Comment: Place the TextView below to Login button.

Comment: I think you have to use `@+id` instead of `@id`

Comment: Did you Try this>? Is this Works?

Answer (score 1):

Replace that textview field attributes with this

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    style="flat_detail_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:capitalize="characters"
    android:text="Sign in Or Register for Your Primium free membership "
    android:textColor="#000000" />
```

It is not suggested to use relative layouts..Instead prefer Linear layouts

Answer (score 0):

You can add an ID for your LinearLayout and change the position of the Sign IN or Register text edit.

android:layout_above="@+id/loginButtonsLinearLayout"

Answer (score 0):

Just put this two lines in your TextView2 containing Text in question

```
<!-- Logo -->

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rel_jobDesc1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="47dip"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/logo" >
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="340dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dip" >

    <!-- JOB DESCRIPTION -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_JOB_DESCRIPTION"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:text="Job Description:"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="14dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_JOB_DESCRIPTION11"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt_JOB_DESCRIPTION"
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true" >
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_JDESCRIPTION"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edit_JOB_DESCRIPTION11"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dip"
        android:text="(Job title, industry, keywords)"
        android:textColor="#4a596e"
        android:textSize="12dip" >
    </TextView>
    <!--  -->


    <!-- LOCATION -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_JOB_LOCATION"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_JDESCRIPTION"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dip"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_SEARCH"
        android:text="Location:          "
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_JOB_LOCATION1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edit_JOB_DESCRIPTION11"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_JDESCRIPTION"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true" >
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_JLOCATION"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edit_JOB_LOCATION1"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dip"
        android:text="(City, State, Zip)"
        android:textColor="#4a596e"
        android:textSize="12dip" >
    </TextView>
    <!--  -->


    <!-- JOB ID -->
    <!--  -->


    <!-- SEARCH BUTTON -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_search1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_JLOCATION"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dip"
        android:background="@drawable/draw"
        android:text="  Search  " >
    </Button>
    <!--  -->

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        style="flat_detail_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_search1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:capitalize="characters"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:text="Sign in Or Register for Your Primium free membership "
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_Login1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/draw"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="  Login  " />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_register"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/draw"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Register" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_lostlogin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/draw"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Lost Login" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rel_jobDesc1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
    android:text="Get Started with Your Job Search"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="14dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: Alright, I have posted entire code now, this should help your case, try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Tested with the eclipse preview on APIs 8 and 17.
Add all the android:backgrounds again, I do not have your drawables.

Steps to do it:

- Move the textview tag to the last one and add the attribute `android:layout_above="@+id/llButtons"`
- Add and id to the linearlayout that contains the buttons like `android:id="@+id/llButtons"`

  ```
          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
          <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
          android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

          <!-- Logo -->

          <RelativeLayout
              android:id="@+id/rel_jobDesc1"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="47dip"
              android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
          </RelativeLayout>

          <RelativeLayout
              android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="340dp"
              android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
              android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
              android:layout_marginTop="100dip" >

              <!-- JOB DESCRIPTION -->

              <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/txt_JOB_DESCRIPTION"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
                  android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                  android:text="Job Description:"
                  android:textColor="#000000"
                  android:textSize="14dip"
                  android:textStyle="bold" >
              </TextView>

              <EditText
                  android:id="@+id/edit_JOB_DESCRIPTION11"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
                  android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                  android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt_JOB_DESCRIPTION"
                  android:maxLines="1"
                  android:singleLine="true" >
              </EditText>

              <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/txt_JDESCRIPTION"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_below="@+id/edit_JOB_DESCRIPTION11"
                  android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="45dip"
                  android:text="(Job title, industry, keywords)"
                  android:textColor="#4a596e"
                  android:textSize="12dip" >
              </TextView>
              <!--  -->


              <!-- LOCATION -->

              <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/txt_JOB_LOCATION"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_below="@+id/txt_JDESCRIPTION"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
                  android:layout_marginTop="50dip"
                  android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_SEARCH"
                  android:text="Location:          "
                  android:textColor="#000000"
                  android:textSize="15dip"
                  android:textStyle="bold" >
              </TextView>

              <EditText
                  android:id="@+id/edit_JOB_LOCATION1"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edit_JOB_DESCRIPTION11"
                  android:layout_below="@+id/txt_JDESCRIPTION"
                  android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
                  android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
                  android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                  android:maxLines="1"
                  android:singleLine="true" >
              </EditText>

              <TextView

                  android:id="@+id/txt_JLOCATION"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_below="@+id/edit_JOB_LOCATION1"
                  android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="45dip"
                  android:text="(City, State, Zip)"
                  android:textColor="#4a596e"
                  android:textSize="12dip" >
              </TextView>
              <!--  -->


              <!-- JOB ID -->
              <!--  -->


              <!-- SEARCH BUTTON -->

              <Button
                  android:id="@+id/btn_search1"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_below="@+id/txt_JLOCATION"
                  android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                  android:layout_marginTop="35dip"
                  android:text="  Search  " >
              </Button>

          </RelativeLayout>

          <LinearLayout
              android:id="@+id/llButtons"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
              android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:weightSum="10" >

              <Button
                  android:id="@+id/btn_Login1"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_margin="5dp"
                  android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                  android:gravity="center"
                  android:text="  Login  " />

              <Button
                  android:id="@+id/btn_register"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_margin="5dp"
                  android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                  android:gravity="center"
                  android:text="Register" />

              <Button
                  android:id="@+id/btn_lostlogin"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_margin="5dp"
                  android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                  android:gravity="center"
                  android:text="Lost Login" />
          </LinearLayout>

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textView1"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_below="@+id/rel_jobDesc1"
              android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
              android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
              android:text="Get Started with Your Job Search"
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:textSize="14dip"
              android:textStyle="bold" />

              <!--  -->

                <TextView
                      style="flat_detail_name"
                      android:capitalize="characters"
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/llButtons"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                   android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
                      android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:text="Sign in Or Register for Your Primium free membership "
                    />
           </RelativeLayout>
  ```